# Series of questions

Tags: discussion

Many people on the worldbuilding website ask series of related questions when building a setting, either because they divide the work into manageable chunks or because they want to follow up on a previous question.

What would be the appropriate way to aggregate links to a series of related questions?

Comment: Most people just link to the other questions inside each question. What else did you have in mind?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that other posts provide context for the current post, the appropriate way is to **link from the post where the context is needed to the posts that provide the context.**

*This does not mean* that every question should be linked to every other question that relates to the same world one is building, or even every previous question posted.

**Link to provide context, not to show off unrelated previous work.** All your existing questions are 2-3 clicks away (click on the username, then click on the "questions" tab) for those who might be interested; that is plenty enough.

Comment: You may also want to link because you wrote out lots of detail in the last post and you don't want to have to have it in both posts.